# How do you map a HTTPResponse with repeating data

Tags: apex, api, httpresponse

I am trying to map the response from an API call. The call is as follows:

```
public Void Jetnet(){
        String SecurityToken = JetnetAPI_SecurityToken();      
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        System.debug('Security Token = ' + SecurityToken);
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.jetnetconnect.com/JetnetDataService.svc/getAircraftHistoryList?modelid=677&startdate=2020');
        req.setHeader('securityToken', SecurityToken.replaceall('"',''));
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http2 = new Http();
        HTTPResponse response = http2.send(req);
        system.debug('status code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            List <AircraftListResult> results = (List<AircraftListResult>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            system.debug('results = ' + results);
            //List<Object> getAircraftHistoryListResult = (List<AircraftListResult>) results.get('getAircraftHistoryListResult');
            //for (Object JNAircraft: getAircraftHistoryListResult){
            //    System.debug(JNAircraft);
            }
        }
```

I created a class to map the response.

```
public class AircraftListResult {
    public integer responseid;
    public string responsestatus;
    public integer count;
    public string pagelink;
    public integer aircraftid;
    public string make;
    public string model;
    public string maketype;
    public string sernbr;
    public string regnbr;
    public string yearmfg;
    public string yeardlv;
    public boolean forsale;
    public boolean exclusive;
    public boolean leasesd;
    public string marketstatus;
    public string asking;
    public integer askingprice; //this should be a decimal, how to declare?
    public date listdate;
    public string basecity;
    public string basestate;
    public string basecountry;
    public integer baseairportid;
    public integer aftt;
    public integer estaftt;
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to handle the values that repeat. Every value before aircraftid only shows up once. all values after repeat hundreds of time as a set of data.

Here is an example of the json response to the call:

```
{
  "getAircraftListResult": {
    "responseid": "14283575",
    "responsestatus": "SUCCESS",
    "count": 353,
    "pagelink": "https://www.jetnetevolution.com/DisplayAircraftDetail.aspx?acid=0&jid=0",
    "aircraft": [
      {
        "aircraftid": 233698,
        "make": "AIRBUS",
        "model": "A320-200",
        "maketype": "Jet Airliner",
        "sernbr": "9329",
        "regnbr": "B-30DX",
        "yearmfg": 2019,
        "yeardlv": 2020,
        "forsale": "false",
        "exclusive": "false",
        "leased": "false",
        "marketstatus": "Not for Sale",
        "asking": null,
        "askingprice": null,
        "listdate": null,
        "basecity": null,
        "basestate": null,
        "basecountry": "China",
        "baseairportid": null,
        "aftt": null,
        "estaftt": null
      },
      {
        "aircraftid": 216232,
        "make": "AIRBUS",
        "model": "A321-200",
        "maketype": "Jet Airliner",
        "sernbr": "9360",
        "regnbr": "N398DN",
        "yearmfg": 2020,
        "yeardlv": 2020,
        "forsale": "false",
        "exclusive": "false",
        "leased": "false",
        "marketstatus": "Not for Sale",
        "asking": null,
        "askingprice": null,
        "listdate": null,
        "basecity": null,
        "basestate": null,
        "basecountry": "United States",
        "baseairportid": null,
        "aftt": null,
        "estaftt": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com). You'll need to clean up your JSON before you feed it to another program.

Comment: I did. I just don't know what to do with it. Sorry, I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do it this way.

1. Create a class to wrap your JSON:

   ```
   public class WrapperRequest {

   public GetAircraftListResult getAircraftListResult;

   public class GetAircraftListResult {
       public String responseid;
       public String responsestatus;
       public Integer count;
       public String pagelink;
       public List<Aircraft> aircraft;
   }

   public class Aircraft {
       public Integer aircraftid;
       public String make;
       public String model;
       public String maketype;
       public String sernbr;
       public String regnbr;
       public Integer yearmfg;
       public Integer yeardlv;
       public String forsale;
       public String exclusive;
       public String leased;
       public String marketstatus;
       public Object asking;
       public Object askingprice;
       public Object listdate;
       public Object basecity;
       public Object basestate;
       public String basecountry;
       public Object baseairportid;
       public Object aftt;
       public Object estaftt;
   }


   public static WrapperRequest parse(String json) {
       return (WrapperRequest) System.JSON.deserialize(json, WrapperRequest.class);
    }
   }
   ```

That one above will do.

Now process your JSON:

```
public Void Jetnet(){
        WrapperRequest wrapper = new WrapperRequest();
        String SecurityToken = JetnetAPI_SecurityToken();      
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        System.debug('Security Token = ' + SecurityToken);
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.jetnetconnect.com/JetnetDataService.svc/getAircraftHistoryList?modelid=677&startdate=2020');
        req.setHeader('securityToken', SecurityToken.replaceall('"',''));
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http2 = new Http();
        HTTPResponse response = http2.send(req);
        system.debug('status code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        wrapper = (WrapperRequest)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),WrapperRequest.class);
        // Now you can access any value from the response by calling 
        // wrapper.GetAircraftListResult.responseid, etc 

        // For Aircraft just do a for loop. 
        for(WrapperRequest.Aircraft wrAir : wrapper.Aircraft) {
         // Your logic.
         }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Carlos!

Comment: Glad it worked out..

Answer (score 0):

The parts in the array need to be in a list:

```
public class Aircraft {
  public String aircraftid;
  public String make;
  // ... //
}
public class AircraftListResult {
  public String responseId;
  public String responsestatus;
  // ... //
  public List<Aircraft> aircraft;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map it so you have a `List<Aircraft` as one of your properties.

```
public class Payload
{
    Result getAircraftResult;
    public class Result
    {
        String responseId, responseStatus, pageLink;
        Integer count;
        List<Aircraft> aircraft;
    }
    public class Aircraft
    {
        Integer aircraftid;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Then you would do:

```
Payload data = (Payload)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, Payload.class);
```